# ffmpeg overlay filter: maintain audio and video quality

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark, video-watermarking

I'm adding a watermark to a video using the [ffmpeg overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1), and I want to preserve the original quality of the video. This is the output of `ffmpeg -i` for the original video:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'original_recording.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
  Duration: 00:03:59.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1932 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1472x828 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1796 kb/s, 24.96 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

and this is the command I'm using to overlay an image file in the bottom right hand corner (basically a watermark):

```
ffmpeg -i original_recording.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=W-w-45:H-h-35" -c:v libx264 -strict -2 output.mp4
```

I added the libx264 option becausee the output was coming out all wibbly. However, when I use this, the size of the output file is much smaller than the original. (There's no noticeable loss in quality when I play the video, but I'd rather not lose quality if possible). I'm very much not an expert on video formats, to be honest I'm a bit lost.

I've tried the -crf option but that gives this error message:

```
Codec AVOption crf (Select the quality for constant quality mode) specified for output file #0 (output.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
```

What would be the best way to overlay an image as a watermark whilst preserving the quality of the original video as much as possible?

Comment: Share the full log of the crf command you tried.

Comment: @Gyan - adding the `-crf 20` to the command actually doesn't give an error now, it must have been before I added the `-c:v libx264`... do you still want the output?

Comment: No, that's all you need.Tweak the CRF till quality/size is ok.

Comment: Ok great, I'm happy with that, thank you. There's an answer about crf options [here](https://superuser.com/a/677580/71016) if it helps anyone else - basically for x264 the valid range is 0-51, 0 being lossless and 51 is worst possible. 18 gives a good result for me.

Comment: Can you share the final command you got please ?

Comment: @MohammedHamdan I don't use this any more, but it was something like this: `ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=W-w-45:H-h-35" output.mp4`